# Android Toolbar color change

Tags: android, colors, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I have an app which uses `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`. Every section of the app is a `Fragment` accessed through a `support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`

I need to change the `Toolbar` color depending on which section is shown (client particular needs).

I defined some colors in the `colors.xml` so I can make something like:

```
changeToolbarColor(R.color.section_one);

/**/

private void changeToolbarColor(int color_res_id){
    Integer colorTo = getResources().getColor(color_res_id);
    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(colorTo);
}
```

The problem is, once I do this, every view using the `primaryColor` (the original primary color from the toolbar) now shows up using the **new** color of the Toolbar.

So if my Toolbar was *green* and I change it to *red*, now *everything* using the old green uses red instead.

I suspect, that the change of the Toolbars background changes the `primaryColor` definition itself (which makes no sense to me). Because I have no other idea of how unrelated elements in unrelated activities start using the same color.

Is this a bug? Anyone with this problem? Any workarounds available?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I guess (but not sure) that you should create different themes and recreate the toolbar depending on the selection, but probably this is not the best behavior

Comment: I thought about it @tizionario and I agree with you. It seems not the best approach. It looks like Toolbar's color has to be easy to change. But apparently it isn't, maybe using `Palette` or any other approach? But I can't think of a propper way of doing it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all themes are **immutable**, so it's not possible to change the primary color of the app.

And try using `getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable()`.

I guess it's something else which is causing the issue. Can you post more code ?

Comment: Thx @Aky for the answer, but it's not the `theme` I'm trying to change but the `Toolbar` color, which is defined by the value put on the `primaryColor` (in `themes.xml`)
I mean, if the primary color is red, I want it to stay red, so every other element stays red. But the toolbar, I may want it to be green, blue or whatever I need. But once I change toolbar's color, every other element using the `primaryColor` color changes aswell.

Comment: @EloiNavarro
Ohhkay, But did you try `getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable()` ?

Comment: I must admit it, I wasn't sure this was going to show any difference at all. But indeed, it solved my issue. Thank you very much!