# Android selector with icon

Tags: android, icons, selector, drawable

I'm trying to get the icon changing color when I press the icon like the toolbar on Instagram or like this [Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjsql.png)

I have searched and the only findings is the case of the button with text, I need with Icons.Thanks

Comment: you could do at runtime. check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32657160/3425390).

Comment: I believe the best way to do this, is to create two kind of icons. That means two states. Unselected and Selected. In your files, have home_icon_selected.png(blue thing) and home_icon_unselected.png.(grey thing) Then onClick of this button(Image/View or whatever) check the current image background/src and if it's not the "home_icon_selected.png" change it to that.

Comment: Thanks @Tony am trying to follow your steps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Vector Assets, then you can change the color in the xml with:

```
android:tint="@color/myColor" or android:tint="#ff00ff"
```

I recommend you use the colors.xml in the values folder. That way you can change the colors through the whole project at one place :)

Or in the code with:

```
iconName.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ff00ff"));
```

If you want the color change to happen on a click, toggle or different event. Then you would just need to apply the corresponding listener.
For example a OnClickListener if you want this to happen on a click.

```
nameOfClickableObject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //to do code here
        }
    });
```

Edit: What are you currently using to display the icons? Have you got anything you could share?